# Make HTML tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, session

I have some php code `$_SESSION['username']` and I need to display it using html with something like `<p>the username here</p>`. I heard you might be able to do this using `echo` in PHP but Im not sure how. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's not a `HTML label`, but a `HTML tag`.

`<label>` is a `HTML tag` too! :)

Comment: Agreed with @nice. This thread is a bit of a misnomer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo '<p>' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</p>';
```

or

```
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></p>
```

You should really run it through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid breaking your HTML syntax (for example if the user's name contains `</p>` or something, or if they attempt an [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)):

```
echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']) . '</p>';
```

Comment: You should always use `htmlspecialchars` to put text into HTML, whether it came from the user or not. It's a matter of correctness as much as security! (Except of course in the case where you deliberately want to inject literal HTML, which is comparatively rare.)

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, I believe you are looking for:

```
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['username'].'</p>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.useful.php